# Photos app offering to import existing photos from iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, photos

When I connect my iPhone to my MacBook Pro and open Photos app and click on the iPhone in order to import the latest photos, hundreds of already existing (in Photo library) photos are among the new items for import. I already tried to import them and then deleting the duplicated in Photo app but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't you see three options: Import / Import Selected / Import All New Items? You could use the second or third option?

Comment: I am using that third option but still...

Comment: Hmm. Try repairing the Mac Photos library? (Keeping option-command keys pressed, launch Photos app). May update the import flags in the database.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I have the same problem, in fact the import is even now showing that it will import duplicates of the duplicates!  Repairing the library didn't change anything, I'm not sure what to do but this is terrible.

Comment: @JVC No, I haven't been able to solve this. I still have a library full of duplicates and also of duplicates of the duplicates.